# First touch of onTouch animation not working

Tags: android, animation, touch, listener

in my app, I have implemented a view with 2 fragment panels divided by a divider in the middle. you can drag each of these fragments, which transition into fully viewing them-- Login/signup. My onTouchListener is completely working EXCEPT for the first time you touch the screen. The views jump to some bizarre position and then once you continue dragging, it works. Does anyone know why this is happening??

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    _xDelta = 0;

    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            downXValue = (int) event.getRawX();
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            int currentX = (int) event.getRawX();

            _xDelta = Math.abs(currentX - downXValue);

                if (downXValue < currentX) {

                    _xDelta = currentX - downXValue;

                    if(_xDelta >= 20) {

                        if(_xDelta <= (screenWidth/3)) {

                            lParams.width = initPanelWidth + ((int) (_xDelta * 1.7));
                            loginPanel.view.setLayoutParams(lParams);

                            loginForm.view.setAlpha(getAlpha(lParams.width - initPanelWidth));
                            welcomeFrameLayout.setAlpha(1 - getAlpha(lParams.width - initPanelWidth));
                            registerParent.view.setAlpha(1 - getAlpha(lParams.width - initPanelWidth));
                            dontReset = false;

                        } else{

                            lParams.width = screenWidth;
                            loginPanel.view.setLayoutParams(lParams);

                            rParams.width = 0;
                            registerPanel.view.setLayoutParams(rParams);

                            loginParent.view.setAlpha(0);
                            loginForm.view.setAlpha(1);
                            welcomeFrameLayout.setAlpha(0);
                            registerParent.view.setAlpha(0);
                            dontReset = true;

                        }


                    }

                }else {

                    _xDelta = downXValue - currentX;

                    if(_xDelta <= ((2*screenWidth)/5)) {

                        rParams.width = initPanelWidth + ((int) (_xDelta * 1.7));
                        registerPanel.view.setLayoutParams(rParams);

                        registerForm.view.setAlpha(getAlpha(rParams.width - initPanelWidth));
                        welcomeFrameLayout.setAlpha(1 - getAlpha(rParams.width - initPanelWidth));
                        loginParent.view.setAlpha(1 - getAlpha(rParams.width - initPanelWidth));
                        dontReset = false;

                    } else{

                        rParams.width = screenWidth;
                        registerPanel.view.setLayoutParams(rParams);

                        lParams.width = 0;
                        loginPanel.view.setLayoutParams(lParams);

                        registerParent.view.setAlpha(0);
                        registerForm.view.setAlpha(1);
                        welcomeFrameLayout.setAlpha(0);
                        loginParent.view.setAlpha(0);
                        dontReset = true;


                    }


                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            if(!dontReset) {
                lParams.width = initPanelWidth;
                loginPanel.view.setLayoutParams(lParams);
                loginForm.view.setAlpha(0);

                rParams.width = initPanelWidth;
                registerPanel.view.setLayoutParams(rParams);
                registerForm.view.setAlpha(0);


                welcomeFrameLayout.setAlpha(1);
                loginParent.view.setAlpha(1);
                registerParent.view.setAlpha(1);
            }



        }


    return true;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked to see what `MotionEvent` is being returned? Maybe put in a `default` case and output the `event`.

Comment: it is returning action down @DigitalNinja

Comment: I just realized that you have the break there on purpose? That's how you're getting the `downXValue` before an ACTION_MOVE event?

Comment: yeah. i just took the break out, too, and it didn't do anything @DigitalNinja

Comment: Yeah, nothing stands out for me. Maybe just double check your logic for the calculations. Use the logcat to print some debugging. It seems like something isn't getting set or calculated correctly the first time it's touched.

Answer (score 0):

Add to every view and layout:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```